# Injecting grails-app classes in Grails

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, grails-plugin

**Please note:** Although my specific question at hand involves the [Grails Shiro](https://grails.org/plugin/shiro) plugin, I believe this to be a core *Grails question* at heart. And so any battle weary Grails veteran *should* be able to answer this, regardless of their experience with Grails Shiro.

---

Using the Grails Shiro plugin (via `grails shiro-quick-start`) produces a [Shiro realm class](http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html) under **grails-app/realms**. For instance, running:

```
grails shiro-quick-start --prefix=com.example.me.myapp.Mongo
```

...will produce:

```
myapp/
    grails-app/
        realms/
            com/
                me/
                    myapp/
                        MongoDbRealm.groovy
```

Where `MongoDbRealm` is the Shiro realm.

```
package com.example.me.myapp

class MongoDbRealm {
    FizzClient fizzClient // How to inject?
    BuzzClient buzzClient // How to inject?
    FooFactory fooFactory // How to inject?

    // lots of auth-centric, generated code here...
}
```

Let's pretend that `MongoDbRealm` is very complicated and needs to be injected with lots of complicated objects such as service clients and factories, etc. **How do I properly inject `MongoDbRealm`?**

Will `@PostConstruct` work here? Can I inject Grails services into it like I do with controllers? Something else?

---

*Again*, I would imagine that dependency injection works the same here (with Grails Shiro and my `MongoDbRealm`) as in any other class defined under `grails-app`. I just don't understand how `grails-app/*` dependency injection works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugins that support defining classes under `grails-app` typically do so by defining a new type of artifact, and specify an `ArtefactHandler` implementation to manage that. The Grails `ArtefactHandlerAdapter` class implements that interface and provides a lot of common functionality, so that's often used, and is used in the plugin's [RealmArtefactHandler class](https://github.com/pledbrook/grails-shiro/blob/master/shiro2%2Fsrc%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fapache%2Fshiro%2Fgrails%2FRealmArtefactHandler.java).

Dependency injection would be configured in the `newInstance` method. You can see where I did this for one of my plugins [here](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-dynamic-controller/blob/master/src%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fburtbeckwith%2Fgrails%2Fplugins%2Fdynamiccontroller%2FControllerMixinArtefactHandler.java#L68). Since the Shiro plugin doesn't override that method from the base class, it looks like dependency injection isn't supported.

Note that using `@PostConstruct` (or implementing `InitializingBean`) would work if the realm classes were registered as Spring beans, but it doesn't look like that's the case in this plugin.

I try to avoid using the `Holders` class since in most cases it's straightforward to use DI instead of pulling in dependencies explicitly, but it looks like you will need to use that approach here, e.g. `fizzClient = Holders.applicationContext.fizzClient` (assuming that is registered as the "fizzClient" bean).

Comment: Thanks @Burt Beckwith (+1) - can I assume that `Holders.applicationContext` refers to the `web-app/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`, and furthermore, that I would just configure my clients/factories like normal Spring beans in that `applicationContext.xml`? Thanks again!

Comment: No, ignore that file and don't edit it. It just defines the small parent context. Configure beans in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy using the Spring bean DSL. This is covered in detail in the Grails reference docs.

Comment: Thanks @BurtBeckwith (+1 and green check). FWIW, that fact is *extremely misleading* (as a Grails novice looking inward).  I would vote in strong confidence for the Grails community changing `Holders.applicationContext` to `Holders.resources`, or at least providing an `applicationContext.xml` somewhere inside `grails-app` that users *can* modify like normal Spring beans configs. Every time I run into one of these weird Grails "gotchyas", I am strangely reminded of those early 2000s commercials, ["*lost another one to Ditech!!!*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMyH0KUv_F8).